# Trying to access function arguments from inner function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using `three.js` and a script similar to `OrbitControls` as my controller. In my `main.js` file I have a `THREE.Group()` that is being passed to the controller as an argument. From there, I'm attempting to rotate the entire group. 

Problem 1: once the group is passed to the controller, I can no longer access its properties without making a copy

Problem 2: a copy does not contain the entire `THREE.Group()`, rather only the first child

I've been working on this for hours now and I've tried about 50 different things including anything relevant on stackoverflow. I'm completely out of ideas on how to combat this problem.

main.js

```
let container;
let camera; 
let controls;
let game;
let renderer;
let scene;

function init() {
    container = document.querySelector('#scene-container');
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const fov = 35;
    const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 100;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);

  //***** This is the important line ******
    controls = new THREE.ObjectControls(camera, container, game);

    game = new THREE.Group();
    scene.add(game);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    game.add(mesh1);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh2.position.set(0,1,0);
    game.add(mesh2);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });
}

init();
```

ObjectControls.js

```
THREE.ObjectControls = function (camera, domElement, objectToMove) {
    mesh = objectToMove;
    domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

    function mouseMove(e) {
        //** objectToMove is undefined :( **
        mesh.rotation.y += 3;        
    }
};
```

Expected result is that the entire `THREE.Group()` `game` will be rotated, but the result that I get is that only the first child of `game` is rotated, in this case `mesh1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
controls = new THREE.ObjectControls(camera, container, game);
game = new THREE.Group();
```

There is an error in your code since you pass the `undefined` variable `game` to the ctor of `ObjectControls`. If you assign a new object to `game` one line later, `ObjectControls` does not have a reference to this variable.

The idea is to assign the group object to `game` first and then create `ObjectControls`. You essentially switch both lines.

`three.js R105`

Comment: oh my god what a simple fix I'm crying thank you so much